# height of iframe using vh not the same between mobile and desktop

Tags: css, iframe, colorbox

On [this gallery page](http://www.abc.net.au/btn/topic/welcomebook-gallery.htm) the iframe is styled:

```
iframe {width:100vw;height:84.5vh;}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 999px) {
    iframe {width:100vw;height:81.5vh;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) { 
    iframe {width:100vw;height:77.5vh;}
}
```

[Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) is used to display a larger version of the image. I assume Colorbox positions the image in the middle of the window. Colorbox works fine on desktop but on mobile it seems there is a different understanding on what height the iframe is and the large image is displayed waaaay down the list.

I'm not sure if it's incompatibility with vh units and iFrames, a bug with Colorbox or something else.
*(Note that this problem doesn't appear in the inspector - only on an actual mobile device)*

Answer (score 0):

After using the [mobile safari inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html) to directly see what was happening on mobile I worked out the solution was to add:

```
body, html {    
 overflow: scroll;
 height: 100vh;
}
```

This made Colorbox recognise the proper height. However, I then needed to add a media query for desktop browsers who don't need the overflow (adds additional scroll bars if they're there):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  body, html {overflow: auto;}
}
```

Will need this for the scroll to work as expected - I couldn't find anything recent to tell me there's a better way of doing this?

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```